# How to create a dynamic page header and footer in ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report

I created ssrs report with 4 diffrent grouping. I have a dynamic References ID that I want to print in footer. Is there anyway to create a footer with dynamic result?

I tried with variable and parameter it doesn't work. I'm expecting to print the reference ID in every page and the reference ID should be dynamic not only first result.